# why does my program always say "unrecognised selector sent to instance"?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

this is my main code:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var avatar: UIImageView!
     @IBOutlet weak var nickname: UIButton!

    var tapGesture :UITapGestureRecognizer?

    self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dealTap:")
    self.avatar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)

    nickname.addTarget(self, action: "dealModifyNickname:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dealTap:")
    //tapGesture?.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.avatar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)

    nickname.addTarget(self, action: "dealModifyNickname:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



//modify avatar
func dealTap(sender:AnyObject){
    println("dealTap,dealTap!!!")
    println("i am %x",self)
    Alterview.showMessage("a", delegate: self)
}

//modify nickname
func dealModifyNickname(sender:AnyObject){
    Alterview.showmessage("a", subtitle: "a", cancelbutton: "a", delegate:self)
}
```

I can always modify my avatar and nickname,it can't crash , but once I click the other space(the blank space),it will crash.And it said that "-[__NSCFType dealTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e72160"

Comment: post the crash log. which method is the unrecognized selector?

Comment: "unrecognised selector sent to instance" - that does not provide enough information, show full log.

Comment: -[__NSCFType dealTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f4aaf0
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

Answer (score 0):

You really do need to post the exact message, but I am betting it's because you have showMessage (capital M) in dealTap and showmessage (lower case m) in dealModifyNickname.

Comment: i add parameters like this:
    func dealTap(sender:AnyObject){
        Alterview.showMessage("a", delegate: self)
    }
    
    //修改昵称
    func dealModifyNickname(sender:AnyObject){
        Alterview.showmessage("a", subtitle: "a", cancelbutton: "a", delegate:self)
    }
but still crash.In program,these "a" I can't need to use.So I put null at first.